# I am trying to integrate Flask with Dash and include a global Navigation bar

Tags: python, html, flask, navbar, plotly-dash

I created a base.html file and a navbar.html file which I want to set as a global navbar across all pages. It works well for all the .html files, but when I create dash python file which I integrate into my Flask application, I don't know how to include the navbar to those pages.

Here's code for main file:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(navbar_bp)

Bootstrap(app)

create_dash_application1(app)
create_dash_application2(app)
test_dash(app)

@app.route('/')
def base():
    return render_template('base.html')

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is the code for the base.html file:

```
{%extends "bootstrap/base.html"%}
{%block title%}Home{%endblock%}

{% block navbar %}
    {% include 'navbar.html' %} 
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
<div class="container theme-showcase" role="main" style="margin-top: 75px">
    <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Hello Kirkoswald!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I tried everything. Just want to have the navbar on all pages: homepage as well as all dashboard pages.